# multidots/zf3-rest-api no longer exists

Tags: github, composer-php, zend-framework3, packagist

I've been using this library for a long time in my project, yesterday i tried to install my project with composer and i found out the package was abandoned on packagist and page was not found on github (404), I'm not sure if this package was deleted or restricted access because i don't have any other alternative and my whole project is based on it.

composer response:

> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/multidots/zf3-rest-api.git.git/' not found

Comment: Probably your best shot is to find some fork and use it instead: https://github.com/search?q=zf3-rest-api. Irresponsible vendor is not a thing that you can fix, you can avoid them at best.

Comment: In the company where I work to I adviced to make an internal fork for all the repo that are abandoned but are critical for several company projects, so my advice is, if you still have a local copy or you find a fork just make your own fork and point to it.